SwiftUI state variables are null when opening a sheet
I have a VStack where each item returned in the VStack has a callback to update some state variables in the component, with the intent being to open up a sheet controller with a view that is instantiated with the objects returned in the callback. However, although showingBottomSheet is updated correctly, selectedMarket and selectedBetOutcome are not, and they are nil when I check to see if they exist.
struct PlayerCard: View {
    @State private var showingBottomSheet = false
    @State var selectedMarket: Market?
    @State var selectedBetOutcome: BetOutcome?
    
    let entityBettingMarkets: EntityBettingMarkets
    let markets: [Market]
    
    init(entityBettingMarkets: EntityBettingMarkets) {
        self.entityBettingMarkets = entityBettingMarkets
        self.markets = entityBettingMarkets.matchedMarketTitles.map { market in
            Market(market_id: market, handicap: nil, yesOdds: nil, noOdds: nil, timestamp: entityBettingMarkets.game.gameTime.timestamp, name: market, bookKey: nil, yesBookKey: nil, noBookKey: nil, yesLink: nil, noLink: nil, isPrimary: false, type: .overUnder)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 24) {
            PlayerHeader(entityBettingMarkets: entityBettingMarkets)
            GamePreview(game: entityBettingMarkets.game)
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                ForEach(markets.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    YesNoSection(market: markets[index]) { market, betOutcome in
                        print(market, betOutcome)
                        self.selectedMarket = market
                        self.selectedBetOutcome = betOutcome
                        self.showingBottomSheet = true // Make sure the sheet opens here
                    }
                    if index < markets.count - 1 {
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(
            LinearGradient(gradient: entityBettingMarkets.getEntityGradient(), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .center)
        )
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingBottomSheet) {
            if let selectedMarket = selectedMarket, let selectedBetOutcome = selectedBetOutcome {
                BetPage(selectedMarket: selectedMarket, markets: markets, betOutcome: selectedBetOutcome)
            } else {
                Text("Error: Unable to load bet page")
            }
        }
    }
}

I have tried a LazyVStack, I tried making the VStack into a separate variable? I tried all the LLMs and nothing seemed to work.

this type of question has been asked many many times on SO, look for using .sheet(item:...)
